# Postgresql 9.4 incrementing value issue

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions

I am trying to go from the first table: `test4 (pid, event, time)` and count how many events transition to another (in second table `eventtransitions`).

For instance, in the final table, there should be a +1 count for prev = A and event = B because the first two rows has A happening before B and the pid for both are 1. The issue I am having right now is that my query only increments once, but should actually increment as many times as the transitions occur. The final table should have prev = A event = B with count = 2.

Test4 table:

```
 pid | event |        time         
-----+-------+---------------------
   1 | A     | 2016-09-23 02:21:13
   1 | B     | 2016-09-23 03:24:13
   1 | A     | 2016-09-23 04:21:13
   1 | B     | 2016-09-23 05:21:13
```

Evventtransitions table:

```
 prev | event | count 
------+-------+-------
 C    | B     |     0
 C    | A     |     0
 A    | C     |     0
 B    | C     |     0
 A    | B     |     1
 B    | A     |     1
```

The query I tried is this:

```
update eventtransitions
    set count = count + 1
from 
(select rank() over (order by pid, time) as rank,
    pid, event, time
    from test4) as a 
join
(select rank() over (order by pid, time) as rank,
    pid, event, time
    from test4) as b
    on a.rank = b.rank - 1
    where eventtransitions.event = b.event and prev = a.event
    and a.pid = b.pid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the window function `lag()` in a subquery:

```
UPDATE eventtransitions e
SET    count = COALESCE(count, 0) + t.count
FROM (
   SELECT prev, event, count(*) AS count
   FROM  (
      SELECT lag(pid)   OVER w AS prev_pid, pid
           , lag(event) OVER w AS prev    , event
      FROM   test4
      WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY time)
      ) t
   WHERE   prev_pid = pid  -- only where pid matches
   GROUP   BY prev, event
   ) t
WHERE  e.prev = t.prev
AND    e.event = t.event;
```

Seems like you only want to count rows cases where the previous row has the same `pid`. I eliminated all other.

Aggregate in the next step to get counts.  (That's what you were missing!) Then add the result to the existing count in `eventtransitions`.

`COALESCE` to catch possibly existing NULL values in `eventtransitions`.